# PHP code - what does this part of code mean?

Tags: php, arrays

what does the assignment in this loop do? I don't get the array notation in it :S

```
foreach($fieldvalues as $fieldvalue){
    $insertvalues[] = $fieldvalue;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$insertvalues[]` means insert a new item into the array, its a shortcut of array_push(). Its also preferred as it created lesser overhead whilst the PHP is working.

### Additional:

For those who are unsure how the loop works.

```
foreach($fieldvalues as $fieldvalue)
```

every time the loop... loops, the value `$fieldvalue` becomes the next value a pointer is looking it in the array `$fieldvalues` - thus adding this to a new array `$insertvalues by means of the shortcut syntax mentioned above.

Comment: The syntax is not actually a shortcut for the `array_push` function; the `array_push` function is distinct as it adds one or more elements to the end of the given array. The `array_push` function is infact a shortcut for a loop over an array of provided elements to add to the end of a given array argument, and the `array_push` function uses the `$array[] = $value` syntax - a language feature - to achieve this.

Comment: OK, my semantics were incorrect I agree. I have read [] for a single adding of an item into an array is preferable. Or did I read nonsense?

Comment: [] for a single item is preferable, as it avoids the overhead of a function call.

Answer (score 5):

Add `$fieldvalue` to the end of the `$insertvalues` array.

Answer (score 1):

It inserts a new item at the end of the array.

Other languages tend to have an append or push function for this.

Answer (score 0):

It adds the value of `$fieldvalue` at the end of `$insertvalues` array. The `[]` creates an array and values of the specified variable are added to it at the end each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think, This is variable for New Array.